# Why I can't pass RoutedEventHandler directly in C#

Tags: c#, events, routed-events

I got a UserControl where I want an event to be public:

```
public event RoutedEventHandler CloseButtonClicked;
```

But to dispatch to this event, the following **doesn't** work:

```
public MyUserControl()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    closeButton.Click += CloseButtonClicked;
}
```

While the following **does** work:

```
public MyUserControl()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    closeButton.Click += (sender, args) => CloseButtonClicked(sender, args);
}
```

Why is that?

Comment: Can you show the declaration of the `CloseButtonClicked` method?

Comment: @EdChapel It's on the second line of my question.

Comment: Is `CloseButtonClicked` event really declared in `MyUserControl` (same class you are trying to use it from)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between your two scenarios is when the `CloseButtonClicked` event is evaluated.

In the first, non-working example, the value of the event field is evaluated at the time that the program statement `closeButton.Click += CloseButtonClicked;` is executed. Unless you've already set the field to some useful value, then later when the `Click` event is raised nothing will happen.

In the second, working example, the value of the event field is evaluated at the time that the Click event is raised. That statement declares an anonymous method (via the lambda expression) which on execution invokes the delegate instance stored in the `CloseButtonClicked` event field. So as long as that field gets set before the event is raised, it doesn't matter that the field *wasn't* set when you executed the `closeButton.Click += (sender, args) => CloseButtonClicked(sender, args);` statement.

Note that even the second statement will fail, with a NullReferenceException, if the `CloseButtonClicked` event field hasn't been initialized when the `Click` event is raised. When raising events, you should protect against this by checking for null first (and preferably protecting against any thread race conditions by saving the value into a local first). For example:

```
closeButton.Click += (sender, args)
{
    RoutedEventHandler handler = CloseButtonClicked;

    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler(sender, args);
    }
};
```

Naturally, the above boilerplate is often encapsulated into a helper method (extension or otherwise).

Answer (score 0):

This line doesn't tell what to execute when closeButton.Click occurs:

```
closeButton.Click += CloseButtonClicked;
```

To get actual method into it. You need to set CloseButtonClicked first:

```
CloseButtonClicked += MyMethodWhichDoesSomething;
```

Now create method MyMethodWhichDoesSomething and there raise an event (CloseButtonClicked(sender, e);)

What this line does, it actually creates a method which raises event...

```
closeButton.Click += (sender, args) => CloseButtonClicked(sender, args);
```